# Scroll panel to vertical center of window?

Tags: gwt

I have a FlowPanel with many child panels. It has enough child panels that the browser window automatically presents a vertical scroll bar.

Is there a way to scroll a particular child panel to the center of the browser window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can place a the child panel inside a [scrollPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html), so that each child panel can have a scroll, or select the child panel which you need to scroll.